# How do divisional patent applications work?

Tags: patentability, prior-art, divisional

Is it possible to file a divisional patent for an embodiment briefly described in a granted (own) patent which does not have a specific claim for that embodiment? Is there a time limit that you can do that? And can you add more information about the embodiment in the divisional patent?

Comment: Please search this site with the term “divisional”. There are quite a few related questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

The original application must still be pending when the divisional *application* is filed and no new matter can be added. The purpose is to claim something already disclosed but not yet claimed.